# Gatling for loop in checkif conditional

Tags: scala, loops, dictionary, gatling

im really new to scala and gatling testing. What im trying to do is to extract parameters from response and save it to some session variabels. I want to pass map with variable name, and variable path to be extracted.

```scala
      if(req.method == "GET"){
    scn.exec(http(req.url).get("/uri").check(checkIf(!req.additionalParameters.isEmpty){
        for(par <- additonalParameters){
          jsonPath(par._2).saveAs(par._1)
        }
    }))
  }
```

Im was trying something like this, but it dosen't compile and im wondering if it's even possible to do.
Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible this way atm (as of Gatling 3.3.1), checkIf second parameter takes one single value. You need one checkIf per check.

Comment: If I save whole body response and then search for values in separate exec and save them to session variables that would be ok, right?